# Qt Mobile broadcasting (DVB-H) API

Tags: api, qt, nokia, headset, broadcasting

I want to create a Qt program that uses the DVB-H headset to watch and record programs. I know there is already such a program on the Nokia store but it doesn't work with latest headset. I have already found this http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsptopic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-154101B4-1539-4025-9698-FC1FBF393C0E.html for using the headset with a Java app, but I want to know if there is a Qt version of this API that I can use. I have been looking around but I can't find one, maybe there isn't one. If you know anything about this please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt APIs for DVB-H do not exist. JSR-272 is the only option on Symbian.

Comment: Do you know they are making one and if they are when it will be complete?